# Extraction of specific data from PDF tables in R; how to get column headings?

Tags: r, extract, heading

This code extracts tables of data from a PDF then uses grepl to extract the data with a specfic key word, in this case 'malaria'. It extracts the row names, much misses off column headings and puts NA, I think because of the differing lengths. Is there a way to get the headings?

```
library(tabulizer)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

files <- dir(path = ".", pattern = "\\.pdf$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
mdata <- list()
for(i in files){
  mdata[[i]] <- extract_tables(i)
}


col_names_list <- lapply(mdata[[1]], function(x) x[1,]) # we extract the     first row (colnames)
 data <- lapply(mdata[[1]], function(x) as.data.frame(x[-1, ]))
 data <- map2(mdata, col_names_list, function(x,y) {colnames(x)[0] <- y[0] 
 x})

 searchterms <-c('malaria')#, 'cases')
 pattern <- paste(searchterms, collapse = "|")

 mdata %>% 
   map(function(x) x[grepl(pattern, x[,1], ignore.case = TRUE),, drop =    FALSE])-> df2


m1<-df2[sapply(df2, nrow)>0] #removes obs=0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, there's not enough information to assist you as a link to a sample of the source PDF data was not provided. There's no way to help triage your problem without that.

Comment: What is the easiest way to do this? I only have the pdf on my computer. Google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m7-DYvoW5xmZT_mJhECnOm3nEvuhru28/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The Table 3.1 in that PDF does not appear to be the same as the `list()` output in your question suggests. In the linked PDF it's _"Table 3.1 showing the number of Family Planning Services provided at the Basic Health Facilities by Division in 2005"_ whereas your `list()` shows it is something about malaria.

Comment: @hrbrmstr  My mistake, my plan is to do this for multiple pdfs. So you can run the code on the pdf provided and let me know what you think. (I deleted the output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's super-difficult to have generic solutions to PDF table extraction (even for PDFs from the same agency).

To get table 3.1 in a usable form from the sample doc (Gdocs is decent way to share PDFs, too) here's what I'd do:

```
library(tabulizer)

fil <- "~/Downloads/GBD2016_1_0915 Gambia HIS  SERVICE STATISTICS REPORT 2005.pdf"

(table_3_1 <- tabulizer::extract_tables(file = fil, pages = 23)[[1]])
##       [,1]               [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]    [,6]   [,7]      [,8]    
##  [1,] ""                 "URD"  "CRD"  "LRD"  "NBDE"  "NBDW" "WESTERN" "TOTAL" 
##  [2,] "Total Women Seen" "910"  "1964" "749"  "1,640" "1143" "8961"    "15,367"
##  [3,] "Total Men Seen"   "936"  "613"  "530"  "687"   "150"  "2334"    "5,250" 
##  [4,] "Counselled Only"  "49"   "229"  "71"   "250"   "232"  "809"     "1640"  
##  [5,] "Pills"            "137"  "476"  "221"  "398"   "198"  "2857"    "4287"  
##  [6,] "Depo"             "286"  "725"  "405"  "456"   "511"  "3166"    "5549"  
##  [7,] "Condoms"          "888"  "4247" "1143" "1934"  "3300" "11952"   "23464" 
##  [8,] "Foam"             "0"    "0"    "10"   "2"     "8"    "41"      "61"    
##  [9,] "IUCD"             "1"    "1"    "0"    "0"     "3"    "37"      "42"    
## [10,] "VSC"              "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"     "0"    "0"       "0"     
## [11,] "Total New"        ""     ""     ""     ""      ""     ""        ""      
## [12,] "Acceptors"        "1312" "5449" "1779" "2790"  "1050" "18053"   "30433" 

table_3_1[1,1] <- "measure" # need to add the colname

(table_3_1 <- as.data.frame(table_3_1[-(11:12),], stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
##                  V1  V2   V3   V4    V5   V6      V7     V8
## 1           measure URD  CRD  LRD  NBDE NBDW WESTERN  TOTAL
## 2  Total Women Seen 910 1964  749 1,640 1143    8961 15,367
## 3    Total Men Seen 936  613  530   687  150    2334  5,250
## 4   Counselled Only  49  229   71   250  232     809   1640
## 5             Pills 137  476  221   398  198    2857   4287
## 6              Depo 286  725  405   456  511    3166   5549
## 7           Condoms 888 4247 1143  1934 3300   11952  23464
## 8              Foam   0    0   10     2    8      41     61
## 9              IUCD   1    1    0     0    3      37     42
## 10              VSC   0    0    0     0    0       0      0

(table_3_1 <- docxtractr::assign_colnames(table_3_1, 1)) # note the docxtractr package dependency
##            measure URD  CRD  LRD  NBDE NBDW WESTERN  TOTAL
## 1 Total Women Seen 910 1964  749 1,640 1143    8961 15,367
## 2   Total Men Seen 936  613  530   687  150    2334  5,250
## 3  Counselled Only  49  229   71   250  232     809   1640
## 4            Pills 137  476  221   398  198    2857   4287
## 5             Depo 286  725  405   456  511    3166   5549
## 6          Condoms 888 4247 1143  1934 3300   11952  23464
## 7             Foam   0    0   10     2    8      41     61
## 8             IUCD   1    1    0     0    3      37     42
## 9              VSC   0    0    0     0    0       0      0

table_3_1[,2:8] <- lapply(table_3_1[,2:8], readr::parse_number) # note the readr package dependency

str(table_3_1)
## 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ measure: chr  "Total Women Seen" "Total Men Seen" "Counselled Only" "Pills" ...
##  $ URD    : num  910 936 49 137 286 888 0 1 0
##  $ CRD    : num  1964 613 229 476 725 ...
##  $ LRD    : num  749 530 71 221 405 ...
##  $ NBDE   : num  1640 687 250 398 456 ...
##  $ NBDW   : num  1143 150 232 198 511 ...
##  $ WESTERN: num  8961 2334 809 2857 3166 ...
##  $ TOTAL  : num  15367 5250 1640 4287 5549 ...
```

A similar idiom can be used to transform *most* of the tables on Pages 14 to 17 of the sample PDF:

```
pages_14_to_17 <- tabulizer::extract_tables(file = fil, pages = 14:17)

lapply(pages_14_to_17, function(x) {
  x[1,1] <- "measure"
  x <- as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  x <- docxtractr::assign_colnames(x, 1)
  x[,2:ncol(x)] <- lapply(x[,2:ncol(x)], readr::parse_number)
  x
}) -> pages_14_to_17

str(pages_14_to_17, 1)
## List of 12
##  $ :'data.frame': 11 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 10 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 0 obs. of  7 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 9 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 11 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 11 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 10 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 11 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 11 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 10 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 7 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 8 obs. of  8 variables:
```

(Not putting all the data frames into an answer to save space).

Note that list element 3 has no rows as the table wraps from 14 to 15. There's no "one size fits all" way to handle that and that'd be custom logic in the script to handle going back to page 14 and getting the header for it.

Comment: Thank you! My plan (for now) is to only extract data relating to malaria rather than every single table :)